# in an effort to re-install mysql-server, I deleted some apparmor files. Do I need them?

Tags: mysql, apparmor

Do I need following AppArmor related files which I deleted from my VPS accidentally?

```
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql    
/etc/apparmor.d/snap/abstractions/mysql    
/etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

If yes, Can I just copy a version from my own Linux desktop environment? If not where do I get them? I was on Ubuntu 14.04 with MySQL 5.5

Comment: I believe the apparmor determines the security access level of your mysql so I think it's important

Comment: Does mysql-server work as expected?  Anything fail? You may want to look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apparmor.html

Comment: no it works as expected. nothing fails.

Comment: only I got an error message during installation.  as I had previously deleted the above said files